# Ошибка при запуске бота на telegraf js "telegraf: Unsupported scene"

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Я попытался сделать сцены для телеграмм бота на telegraf js , но у меня выбивает ошибку . Я не смог найти решение проблемы . Ошибка:

```
Error: telegraf: Unsupported scene
    at D:\Projects\bots\BuyBooks\node_modules\telegraf\stage.js:19:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Stage.register (D:\Projects\bots\BuyBooks\node_modules\telegraf\stage.js:17:12)
    at D:\Projects\bots\BuyBooks\node_modules\telegraf\stage.js:13:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Stage (D:\Projects\bots\BuyBooks\node_modules\telegraf\stage.js:13:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\bots\BuyBooks\telegrambot.js:11:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
```

Вот код основного файла:

```
const { Telegraf} = require('telegraf'),
config             = require("./config/config.json"),
{Extra,Markup,Stage ,session} = Telegraf,
bot                = new Telegraf(config.token),
SceneGenerator     = require('./scenes'),
curScene           = new SceneGenerator,
SearchSchene       = curScene.GenSearchSchene,
InfoSchene         = curScene.GenInfoSchene,
BookTopSchene      = curScene.GenBookTopSchene;

const stage = new Stage([SearchSchene, InfoSchene, BookTopSchene])

bot.use(session())
bot.use(stage.middleware())

bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Привет ! Напиши /help чтобы получить больше информации'))
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply('Список моих команд:\n|1. /search - поиск книги|\n|2. /info - краткая информация о книге|\n|3. /bookTop - топ книг с различных сайтов|'))
bot.command('search', async (ctx) => {
    await ctx.scene.enter('search')
})
bot.launch()
```

Вот код с сценами:

```
const Scene = require("telegraf/scenes/base")

class SceneGenerator {
    GenSearchSchene(){
        const search = new Scene('search')
        search.enter(async (ctx) =>{
            await ctx.reply('Для поиска введите название книги')
        })
        search.on('text', async (ctx) =>{
            const name = ctx.message.text
            //проверяем наличие текста
            if(name){
                await ctx.reply('Идёт обработка . Это может занять некоторое время...')
                await ctx.scene.leave();
            }else{
                await ctx.reply("Мне непонятно данное имя")
                await ctx.scene.reenter()
            }
        })
        search.on('message', (ctx) =>{
            ctx.reply('Ты меня за дибила считаешь ?')
        })
        return search;

    }
    GenInfoSchene(){
        const info = new Scene('info')
        info.enter(async (ctx) =>{
            await ctx.reply('Для поиска информации введите название книги')
        })
        info.on('text', async (ctx) =>{
            const name = ctx.message.text
            //проверяем наличие текста
            if(name){
                await ctx.reply('Идёт обработка . Это может занять некоторое время...')
                ctx.scene.leave()
            }else{
                await ctx.reply("Мне непонятно данное имя")
                await ctx.scene.reenter()
            }
        })
        info.on('message', (ctx) =>{
            ctx.reply('Ты меня за дибила считаешь ?')
        })
        return info
    }
    GenBookTopSchene(){
        const bookTop = new Scene('bookTop')
        bookTop.enter(async (ctx) =>{
            await ctx.reply('Введите колличество книг которое хотите получить')
        })
        bookTop.on('text', async (ctx) =>{
            const currAge = Number(ctx.message.text)
            if(currAge && currAge > 0){
                await ctx.reply('Идёт обработка . Это может занять некоторое время...')
                await ctx.scene.leave()
            }else{
                await ctx.reply("Вы ввели не число или число равное/меньше нуля")
                await ctx.scene.reenter()
            }

        })
        bookTop.on('message', (ctx) =>{
            ctx.reply('Ты меня за дибила считаешь ?')
        })
        return bookTop
    }
}
module.exports = SceneGenerator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявление переменных:

```
curScene           = new SceneGenerator,
SearchSchene       = curScene.GenSearchSchene,
InfoSchene         = curScene.GenInfoSchene,
BookTopSchene      = curScene.GenBookTopSchene;
```

Ваше создание инстанса `Stage`:

```
const stage = new Stage([SearchSchene, InfoSchene, BookTopSchene])
```

Описание конструктора `Stage`:

```
const Stage: new <SceneContextMessageUpdate>(
  scenes: Scene<SceneContextMessageUpdate>[],
  options?: Partial<SceneContextOptions>
) => Stage<...>
```

---

Дело в том, что в переменных *SearchSchene, InfoSchene, BookTopSchene* - "фабрики" объектов, но не инстансы `Scene`, которые ожидает `Stage`.

В вашем коде правильным вызовом было бы

```
const stage = new Stage([SearchSchene(), InfoSchene(), BookTopSchene()])
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное . Два дня не мог понять что нет так