# не работают сцены telegraf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

выдает ошибку когда пытаюсь инициализировать сцены в Stage
Ошибка:

```
         throw new Error('telegraf: Unsupported scene');
Error: telegraf: Unsupported scene
at C:\Users\User\Desktop\IchiroTg\node_modules\telegraf\lib\scenes\stage.js:17:23
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Stage.register (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IchiroTg\node_modules\telegraf\lib\scenes\stage.js:15:16)       
at C:\Users\User\Desktop\IchiroTg\node_modules\telegraf\lib\scenes\stage.js:12:40
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at new Stage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IchiroTg\node_modules\telegraf\lib\scenes\stage.js:12:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IchiroTg\index.js:8:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

index.js:

```
const { token, allowedUsers } = require('./config.json');
const ScenesGenerate = require('./libs/Scenes.js');

const bot = new Telegraf(token);
const scenes = new ScenesGenerate;
const scenesLogging = scenes.loggining;
const stage = new Stage([ scenesLogging() ])
bot.use(session())
bot.use(stage.middleware())


const fs = require('fs');


bot.start((ctx) =>  {
    if (ctx.from.username === allowedUsers[0]) return ctx.reply(`Привет создатель!
    /admin
    /stats
    /examples
    `)
   return ctx.reply(`Привет ${ctx.from.username}, нажми на -> /description`);
})
bot.command('description', (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.reply(`Привет, данный бот не предназнчен для массовго пользования.\nБот оказывает услуги, по мониторингу и помощи в работе небольшим коммнадам в it\nДля пользования ботом нужно иметь секретные ключи верефикации.`) 
    // сделать опрос для кнопки верефикации после переход в логин сцену

})
bot.command('login', (ctx) => {
    ctx.scene.enter('loggining')
})


bot.launch()
```

Scenes.js:

```
const { enter, leave, reenter } = Stage;

class Scenes {
    loggining() {
        const loggining = new BaseScene('loggining');
        loggining.enter(async (ctx) => {
            await ctx.reply('Напиши код верефикатор')
        })
        loggining.on('message', (ctx) => {
            ctx.reply('Нельзя пересылать сообщение!');
            return ctx.scene.reenter();
        });
        loggining.on('text', async (ctx) => {
            const userKeyInputVereficateCode = String(ctx.message.text);
            if(userKeyInputVereficateCode === verificateCode) {
                await ctx.reply(`Вы успешно авторизавались! ✅`);
                return 
            }
            else {
                ctx.reply('Код верефикации неверный, введите снова! ❌');
                ctx.scene.reenter();
                return
            }
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Scenes
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1191089/2659

Comment: только у вас ещё и loggining ничего не возвращает